# Trabajar con Laravel y Vue cli

Tags: laravel, ajax, vue.js, fetch, vue-cli

Mi duda es como trabajo con un proyecto que usa estos dos frameworks y como es el deploy del mismo. Vi algunas sugerencias como:

- Ubicar el proyecto creado con Vue Cli, dentro de la carpeta `resources/frontend/` del proyecto laravel.
- Crear el proyecto con dos carpetas dentro, una que hace referencia al backend(proyecto laravel) y otra que hace referencia al fronend(vue).

**Pero** con eso nomas sé la estructura de carpetas. Sin embargo sigo sin saber **como consumo la api que creé con laravel, desde el frontend**.

- ¿Cómo serian las peticiones ajax?
- ¿Tengo que usar rutas absolutas que apunten a mi backend?

  ```
  let response = await fetch("http://localhost:8000/api/posts") /*donde esta el proyecto laravel*/
  let data = await response.json()
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Para ello debes utilizar tus rutas api amigo, lo mejor es que crees las rutas en api.php, creas las rutas, los metodos tal cual como lo haces en web.php luego ya en vue debes utilizar axios, igual puede ser fetch pero me gusta mas axios, puede colocar la ruta de la api en el axios, a modo de ejemplo para que te de una idea:

```
 methods: {
            axios.get(aqui tu ruta api).then
              retornar una promesa
    }
```

o bien puedes utilizar async await... podrías revisar algunos vídeos en youtube e ir al foro de Vue en https://forum.vuejs.org/

Comment: Sisi, entiendo pero yo tengo el front y el back servidos en distintos puertos del localhost. Osea que si yo ejecuto:

axios.get("/api/posts")

No me dará un 404? Ya que en el front no hay ninguna ruta /api/posts
Pregunto, sinceramente nose si pasará eso

Comment: debes crear tu ruta para los componentes, como un menu en bootstrap, esos componentes llaman a la api desde axios... mientras tengas tus rutas api como publicas no deberias tener problemas, pero cuando ya apliques seguridad a ellas, utilizando middleware deberas hacer las configuraciones necesarias, puedes partir probando a ver que te resulta, dependera si ya tienes las rutas protegidas o no...

Comment: Buenisimo, voy a intentar profundizar mas con lo que me dijiste, Gracias